# rsyslog: how to cut string from starting field to end of message

Tags: rsyslog

i have some messy devices which i want to handle trough rsyslog
90% of job is done, but i am stuck here

```
rawmsg: '<133>2022-07-15 17:11:11 eleservice-sw02 51891 Logout the web by admin on web (169.254.101.1).'
rawmsg: '<133>2022-07-15 17:11:14 eleservice-sw02 51890 Login the web by admin on web (169.254.101.1).'
rawmsg: '<132>2022-07-15 18:10:14 piknov29-sw42 43557 CPU RISING THRESHOLD: Total CPU Utilization is 83%.'
```

so my question is how to select string from Field nr 5 (F,32:5) until end of line ?

Answer (score 0):

After all, looks like i need to use regex

```
template(name="jetstream"
type="string"
string= "%fromhost%||%syslogfacility%||%syslogpriority%||%syslogseverity%||%msg:F,32:3%||%$year%-%$month%-%$day% %timegenerated:8:25%||%msg:R,ERE,4,FIELD:(\\s)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(\\s)(.+)--end%||tp-link\n")
```

key is:

```
%msg:R,ERE,4,FIELD:(\\s)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(\\s)(.+)--end%
```

it is far from nice, but it is working.
My first experience with rsyslog/regex